# Installing NodeJS with Vagrant shell provisioner not working

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm trying to install node.js and some packages through Vagrant and shell provisioner.

I find three cases:

1- Simple `vagrant up` and introducing commands manually once inside `vagrant ssh`

- This one works perfectly, thats why I dont understand why the next 2 cases doesn't

2- Installing from bootstrap.sh called in VagrantFile with privileges:false

- During `vagrant up` everything is installed (it even says "`Now using node v0.11.14`"
- Once inside `vagrant ssh` node, nvm and npm are in my vagrant user folder, but `node` command is not recognized, as well as `npm`. `nvm` is recognized but `nvm ls` lists nothing.

3- Installing from bootstrap.sh called in VagrantFile with privileges:true

- During `vagrant up` everything is installed (it even says "`Now using node v0.11.14`"
- node, nvm and npm are installed in /root directory. node_modules is in the vagrant user directory.
- Commands node and npm not found

Here the contents of VagrantFile and bootstrap.sh

**VagrantFile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 8081

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap.sh", privileged: false

  config.vm.synced_folder "Server", "/home/vagrant/Server"

end
```

**bootstrap.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.17.2/install.sh | bash

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install 0.11.14

npm install express
npm install -g nodemon
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familier with nvm, so I got a question: If you install nvm and everything manually, then log out (exit) and ssh again. Does it work? I'd assume you have to add ~/.nvm to your path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add `nvm use 0.11.14` or add `nvm alias default 0.11.14` to your provisioning script so that nvm know which version to use when you run an npm or node command.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find where it is, you always have $PATH:

```
$vagrant@box# echo $PATH
```

will give you something like

```
/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.18/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

So try

```
$vagrant@box# sudo su
$root@box# /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.18/bin/npm install -g qunit --save
```

(^^ eg when I installed qunit, vagrant had the alias but no permission)

You might need sudo - not a bad idea for npm anyway. My provisioning (Vagrant+ansible) uses root for most things.